A movie about competing male and female college groups
So I watched this movie last year with my friends but I cant seem to remember what it's called. It's taken place in college and there are two big groups on the campus, one for men and the other for women. Both of these groups are run by a guy, and that he decides only one group can own a clubhouse.
So these two groups have to compete against each other and one of the member from the male group decided to send his cousin to the women's group as a spy. The rule of this competition is that they can use whatever method necessary to get rid of the member from each group, since  both groups will stay at the clubhouse. At the end, both group realized they are being played by the guy so they come up with a plan to kick him out.

Sounds like Alpha House from 2014.

When two freshmen pledges are accepted into the biggest party frat on campus (ALPHA HOUSE), they think they have it all. That is, until the assistant dean forces the Alphas to share their house with a sorority or face expulsion from school. Not wanting to see their lifelong dream of becoming Alphas destroyed, the pledges convince the other members of the house to take back what's theirs, waging an epic battle of the sexes to fight for their right to party.

Pretty sure the guys use a cousin (named Natalie) as a spy, and that both clubs join forces in the end. However, this is not a drama. Really, really, not... :P Here's the trailer [Warning: Asylum Movie]:




"[Warning: Asylum Movie]" definitely deserves a +1.  That's a great disclaimer.
